# Maximum Likelihood Estimate for a uniparametric family

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Say we have a simple random sample of size $n$ distributed according to a function of the family:
$$
f(x|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1+x)^{1+\theta}}
$$
where $\theta >0$.

We want to compute the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$.

---

I have tried the following. We want to calculate the $\theta$ which maximizes the likelihood function of a given sample $\vec{x}$, but that coincides with the maximum of the log of the likelihood function.

To calculate it, we try to find the zeros of its derivative:
$$
\ln{L(\theta|\vec{x})} = n\ln{\theta}-(1-\theta)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+x_i)}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\ln{L(\theta|\vec{x})} =
\frac{n}{\theta} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+x_i)}
$$
The solution when we equate this expression to zero is $\theta=-\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+x_i)}}$, which is negative and thus cannot be the MLE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the log-likelihood be $$n \log \theta - (1 + \theta) \sum_{i=1}^n \log (1+x_i)?$$

Comment: @heropup oops my mistake. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question denominator has $1+\theta$, while in your calculations, you are using $1-\theta$. Once you fix this minus sign in your calculations, you will have the same result as you have, without the minus sign.